# Preg_match string inside curly braces tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'd like to grab a string between tags. My tags will be with curly braces.

```
{myTag}Here is the string{/myTag}
```

So far I have found `#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s` This one matches tags with angle brackets `<>`. I couldn't figure out how to make it look for curly braces.

Eventually I would like to parse whole page and grab all matches and build an array with strings.

This is the code:

```
function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#<\s*?$tagname\b[^>]*>(.*?)</$tagname\b[^>]*>#s";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}

$var = everything_in_tags($string, $tagname);
```

Comment: Neither `{` nor `}` need escaping in PHP regex. I think you are looking for something like [`{(\w+)[^{}]*}(.*?){\/\1}`](https://regex101.com/r/zI3uY5/2).

Comment: @user2959229 I can't figure out how to and where to put { in that code, where is the original <

Comment: @Uchiha your code grabs tag names, and I wanted to grab the string between.

Comment: @mrGott [Check This](https://3v4l.org/EWGAu)

Comment: Please post *the whole page* sample text.

Comment: @stribizhev Whole text? it will be just some large text with occurrences of  {myTag}Here is the string{/myTag} 2, 3, maybe 10 times.

Comment: So for multiple occurrence you need to use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

Comment: @Uchiha thank you for your replies, could you please post an answer with the correct regex pattern?

Comment: @mrGott: Are there any nested patterns?

Comment: @stribizhev what do you mean by nested patterns?

Comment: Can there be `{m}str {n}one{/n}{/m}`?

Comment: you can use this `{(.+?)}(.+){\/\1}`. first match of group two will be what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `<` and `>` with `{` and `}` and change `preg_match()` to preg_match_all()` to catch multiple occurrences of text inside those tags.

```
function everything_in_tags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = "#{\s*?$tagname\b[^}]*}(.*?){/$tagname\b[^}]*}#s";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}


$string = '{myTag}Here is the string{/myTag} and {myTag}here is more{/myTag}';
$tagname = 'myTag';
$var = everything_in_tags($string, $tagname);
```

Forget about what I mentioned about escaping the curly brackets - I was mistaken.

Comment: What about `[^>]`? Why did you keep them as is? I will repeat: Neither `{` nor `}` need escaping in PHP regex.

Comment: @stribizhev - apologies... I was mistaken about the escaping and simply missed the other brackets. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @stribizhev actually this code works fine, what does [^>] this one do? should I cut it out?

Comment: I think this solution from user2959229 works just fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: The regex is not the best one to use here. However, if you are OK with it - great, I will not post my solution.

Comment: @stribizhev what is the best use? I don't know if there are other solutions.

Comment: @stribizhev I think its better that you post your answer for future users

Comment: @Uchiha: I think I have posted a lot of similar solutions these days. No need to replicate. I would just note that in a double-quoted string, ``\`` is treated as an escape symbol for escape sequences. Thus, it is more appropriate to use `\\s` instead of `\s` here (although single-backslashed classes work, too).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are building a general use helper function.  For this reason, it is important that you escape any characters with special meaning to the regex engine.  To escape characters with special meaning, use `preg_quote()`.

We don't know the quality of the text that you are searching through, nor do we know the variability of your tag names.  There will be some cases where it will be vital to use the `m` (multibyte) pattern modifier so that unicode characters are read correctly.  The `s` pattern modifier tells the regex engine that the "any character" dot in the pattern should also match newline characters.  The default behavior of the "any character" dot is not to match newline characters.  If you need to accommodate tagnames of unknown upper/lower casing, use the `i` pattern modifier.

If the quality of your curly tags' contents is absolutely sure to not include any opening curly braces, then you could change `(.*?)` to `([^{]*)` to allow the regex to perform more efficiently.

By capturing and referencing the tagname in its opening tag, you slightly reduce the step count of the pattern and reduce the total length of the pattern.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WaFNs))

```
$text = <<<TEXT
some text {myTag}Here is the string
on two lines{/myTag} some more text
TEXT;

function curlyTagContents(string $string, string $tagname): string
{
    $pattern = '/\{(' . preg_quote($tagname, '/') . ')}(.*?)\{\/\1}/s';
    return preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches) ? $matches[2] : '';
}

var_export(
    curlyTagContents($text, 'myTag')
);
```

Output:  (the single quotes are from `var_export()`)

```
'Here is the string
on two lines'
```